# Using GWibber as "desktop background"?

Tags: gwibber, desktop-background

Is there any way to set an application, in this case Gwibber, in the background of the desktop?

This means basically having it in the background showing tweets and if I don't click it, like, I don't know, twice, then I'm not "interacting" with it and it is not enabled.

If the question is not clear comment it and I will correct what's unclear.

Comment: like what ActiveX does in Windows?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with what ActiveX does...

Comment: Activex can be used to, for example set a webpage as your background. as the person below said, you can use compiz, but they waye he described it, the window controls of gwibber would be still be visible.

Comment: I see. Yeah, something like that. That's something I saw on Win98 :D

Comment: Still waiting for the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Through various Compiz plugins (from the extra package, I guess), you can maximize a window (by title), and put it in the background (possibly even making it unclickable). I'm afraid that I forgot what the specific plugins were.

In addition, I never tried this with Unity. I expect results better than before, because the programs menu bar will never be visible, and maximized windows only have controls in the panel -- which will be busy doing other things.